# Concat or not to concat external scripts?

Tags: javascript, html

My site uses a variety of JS scripts. With the ones that I write, I concat to one master JS file.

I have a number of external scripts for things like Pinterist sharing, or Google's places API.

Should these be downloaded and concatenated into my master JS file or should I leave them as a separate call to each of their APIs, as so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: Have you looked into [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)? I use that to combine all my scripts, then call them when needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think concatination of external scripts is a BAD idea.

What about security fixes and updates? You would loose all of that. Many resources like Google etc get updated regularly, so you would have to check it, download it and concatinate. That is too much work for 'having one master JS file'.